# "reason given" vs "given reason"

Tags: adjectives, word-order, postpositive-adjectives

Which is grammatically superior?

> The Hallows are a dangerous place, but if that is the *reason given* to abandon him, then she would forge ahead.
>
> The Hallows are a dangerous place, but if that is the *given reason* to abandon him, then she would forge ahead.

thoughts?

Comment: reason [that is] given; the other is ungrammatical in English.

Comment: @Lambie: Here are [About 3,090 results](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22the+given+reason%22) in Google Books from writers who obviously disagree with you.

Comment: Oh, I see. I thought about that but I suppose I had gotten so used to spoken English that I thought my choices were just as good.

Comment: @FumbleFingers wow what a cool tool! I had no idea that one could do that. Thanks for showing me that. Does it only search Preview sections, or every book that has an ebook for sale?

Comment: I shan't make the exegetical effort for most of those hits. The grammar is different, the commas are missing, the meaning is different and there are loads of translations. That said, I repeat that here:/ but if that is the given reason to abandon him/ is agrammatical in English.

Comment: Your first sentence is the right one. 'Given reason'; we can use with a different context and function. Given reason, he complies easily. Maybe someone can give a better example.

Comment: @Jaico: Google [scanned millions of **paper** books](http://www.wired.com/2013/11/google-2/) besides ebooks. But there are [copyright issues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Books#Copyright_infringement.2C_fair_use_and_related_issues) still being resolved. I think the searches are always on the full text, regardless of how much surrounding *context* you can ["legitimately" or not] access free through GB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The former.

'That is the reason given' is interpreted by English speakers to implicitly read 'that is the reason *that is* given'. The latter is awkward in this case because 'the given reason' is singular, and in context this doesn't seem correct. Surely if it's common knowledge that the Hallows are a dangerous place, this reason would have been given multiple times. And there'd be more than one possible reason to abandon him.

'**a** given reason' would fix the second sentence, but then 'forge ahead' becomes too ambiguous.

Comment: Quite true. It's *possible* to contrive a context where *the given reason* would be "preferred" (though it sure ain't easy! :) The point being the less likely sequence isn't inherently ungrammatical; it just doesn't really suit OP's context.